# How to Hide Fragment Fields dynamically in fiori app

Tags: xml, sapui5

[image]I have a requirement to hide a fragment view field in one of my fiori apps, There are no extensions available to do this!

I tried to write a hook method 'onafterrendering' in a custom container of the main view but still not able to succeed!

Could any of one you guide me to hide fragment view field dynamically in the called app?

Thanks and Regards
Ranjith Rupireddy

Tried with the below code in custom control of main view ( In extension of Fiori app)

```
onAfterRendering : function(){

  var buttonToHide = this.getView().byId("changePictureBtn");

  buttonToHide.setVisible(false);

},
```

I should hide the fragment field as attached with this Question..

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```
var oPictureButton = sap.ui.getCore().byId("changePictureBtn");
oPictureButton.setVisible(false);
```